# In autotools, what is dnl'ed?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, m4

I see a lot in autoconf code about stuff being dnl'ed and not dnl'ed. What is dnl'ed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from the [*GNU M4 1.4.13 macro processor*](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html) manual:

> [8.1 Deleting whitespace in input](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Dnl)
>
> The builtin `dnl` stands for “Discard to Next Line”:
>
> — Builtin: **dnl**
>
> > All characters, up to and including the next newline, are discarded without performing any macro expansion. A warning is issued if the end of the file is encountered without a newline.
> >
> > The expansion of `dnl` is void.
>
> It is often used in connection with `define`, to remove the newline that follows the call to `define`. Thus
>
> ```
>    define(`foo', `Macro `foo'.')dnl A very simple macro, indeed.
>    foo
>    ⇒Macro foo.
> ```
>
> The input up to and including the next newline is discarded, as opposed to the way comments are treated (see [Comments](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Comments)).
>
> [...]

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, [`dnl`](http://uw714doc.sco.com/cgi-bin/info2html?%28m4%29Dnl&lang=en) is `do-next-line`. It simply skips the remainder of the current line. It's how you write comments in M4 files.

```
dnl preprocessor will eat this
but not this dnl though this
```

will yield the result document

```
but not this
```

(untested; might also kill the idle process or crash your hard disk).